# How to get the coupon code discount amount for the current session order in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to find a code that will give me the discount amount for the current session order when I discount code is used.

Here is what I have right now but it is not working:

```
        $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
        $couponCollection = $coupon->getCollection();
        foreach($couponCollection as $c){
            $CouponDiscount = $c->getDiscountAmount();
        }
        echo $CouponDiscount;
```

How can I get the amount of the discount used in the current session order ?

Comment: Aside: quite a few of your questions have a title in the form `tag - title`. The community has discussed this "home-made tagging" on _Meta_ and has decided we prefer titles without that. Write titles in natural English please, as per my edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the current discount amount for your customers quote please see here:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33761